# Why the OpenMP SIMD directive reduces performance?

Tags: fortran, openmp, simd

I am learning how to use SIMD directives with OpenMP/Fortran. I
wrote the simple code:

```
program loop
      implicit none
      integer      :: i,j
      real*8       :: x

      x = 0.0

      do i=1,10000
           do j=1,10000000
                x = x + 1.0/(1.0*i)
           enddo
      enddo

      print*, x


end program loop
```

when I compile this code and run it I get:

```
ifort -O3 -vec-report3 -xhost loop_simd.f90 
loop_simd.f90(10): (col. 12) remark: LOOP WAS VECTORIZED
loop_simd.f90(9): (col. 7) remark: loop was not vectorized: not inner loop

time ./a.out 
   97876060.8355515     

real    0m8.940s
user    0m8.937s
sys 0m0.005s
```

I did what the compiler suggested about the "not inner loop" and
added a SIMD collapse(2) directive:

```
program loop
      implicit none
      integer      :: i,j
      real*8       :: x

      x = 0.0

!$omp simd collapse(2) reduction(+:x)
      do i=1,10000
           do j=1,10000000
                x = x + 1.0/(1.0*i)
           enddo
      enddo

      print*, x


end program loop
```

then I compiled and run the code again and I got the following 
output:

```
ifort -O3 -vec-report3 -openmp -xhost loop_simd.f90 
loop_simd.f90(8): (col. 7) remark: OpenMP SIMD LOOP WAS VECTORIZED

time ./a.out 
   97876054.9903757     

real    0m26.535s
user    0m26.540s
sys 0m0.003s
```

What I don't know is why the performance decreases with SIMD?
And when SIMD will be better than standard Fortran code?

```
    .section .text
.LNDBG_TX:
# mark_description "Intel(R) Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler XE for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 14.0.2.144 Build 2";
# mark_description "0140120";
# mark_description "-O3 -vec-report3 -openmp -xhost -S";
    .file "loop_simd.f90"
    .text
..TXTST0:
L__routine_start_MAIN___0:
# -- Begin  MAIN__
# mark_begin;
       .align    16,0x90
    .globl MAIN__
MAIN__:
..B1.1:                         # Preds ..B1.0
..___tag_value_MAIN__.1:                                        #1.9
..LN0:
  .file   1 "loop_simd.f90"
   .loc    1  1  is_stmt 1
        pushq     %rbp                                          #1.9
..___tag_value_MAIN__.3:                                        #
..LN1:
        movq      %rsp, %rbp                                    #1.9
..___tag_value_MAIN__.4:                                        #
..LN2:
        andq      $-128, %rsp                                   #1.9
..LN3:
        subq      $128, %rsp                                    #1.9
..LN4:
        movq      $0x0000117fe, %rsi                            #1.9
..LN5:
        movl      $3, %edi                                      #1.9
..LN6:
        call      __intel_new_feature_proc_init                 #1.9
..LN7:
                                # LOE rbx r12 r13 r14 r15
..B1.12:                        # Preds ..B1.1
..LN8:
        vstmxcsr  (%rsp)                                        #1.9
..LN9:
        movl      $.2.3_2_kmpc_loc_struct_pack.1, %edi          #1.9
..LN10:
        xorl      %esi, %esi                                    #1.9
..LN11:
        orl       $32832, (%rsp)                                #1.9
..LN12:
        xorl      %eax, %eax                                    #1.9
..LN13:
        vldmxcsr  (%rsp)                                        #1.9
..___tag_value_MAIN__.6:                                        #1.9
..LN14:
        call      __kmpc_begin                                  #1.9
..___tag_value_MAIN__.7:                                        #
..LN15:
                                # LOE rbx r12 r13 r14 r15
..B1.2:                         # Preds ..B1.12
..LN16:
        movl      $__NLITPACK_0.0.1, %edi                       #1.9
..LN17:
        call      for_set_reentrancy                            #1.9
..LN18:
                                # LOE rbx r12 r13 r14 r15
..B1.3:                         # Preds ..B1.2
..LN19:
   .loc    1  8  is_stmt 1
        movl      $4, %eax                                      #8.7
..LN20:
   .loc    1  6  is_stmt 1
        vxorpd    %ymm2, %ymm2, %ymm2                           #6.7
..LN21:
   .loc    1  8  is_stmt 1
        vmovd     %eax, %xmm0                                   #8.7
..LN22:
        xorl      %eax, %eax                                    #8.7
..LN23:
        vpshufd   $0, %xmm0, %xmm1                              #8.7
..LN24:
        vmovdqu   .L_2il0floatpacket.19(%rip), %xmm0            #8.7
..LN25:
                                # LOE rbx r12 r13 r14 r15 eax xmm0 xmm1 ymm2
..B1.4:                         # Preds ..B1.6 ..B1.3
..LN26:
   .loc    1  11  is_stmt 1
        vcvtdq2ps %xmm0, %xmm3                                  #11.34
..LN27:
        vrcpps    %xmm3, %xmm5                                  #11.28
..LN28:
        vmulps    %xmm3, %xmm5, %xmm4                           #11.28
..LN29:
        vaddps    %xmm5, %xmm5, %xmm6                           #11.28
..LN30:
        vmulps    %xmm5, %xmm4, %xmm7                           #11.28
..LN31:
   .loc    1  10  is_stmt 1
        xorl      %edx, %edx                                    #10.12
..LN32:
   .loc    1  11  is_stmt 1
        vsubps    %xmm7, %xmm6, %xmm8                           #11.28
..LN33:
        vcvtps2pd %xmm8, %ymm3                                  #11.28
..LN34:
                                # LOE rbx r12 r13 r14 r15 eax edx xmm0 xmm1 ymm2 ymm3
..B1.5:                         # Preds ..B1.5 ..B1.4
..LN35:
   .loc    1  10  is_stmt 1
        incl      %edx                                          #10.12
..LN36:
   .loc    1  11  is_stmt 1
        vaddpd    %ymm3, %ymm2, %ymm2                           #11.17
..LN37:
   .loc    1  10  is_stmt 1
        cmpl      $10000000, %edx                               #10.12
..LN38:
        jb        ..B1.5        # Prob 99%                      #10.12
..LN39:
                                # LOE rbx r12 r13 r14 r15 eax edx xmm0 xmm1 ymm2 ymm3
..B1.6:                         # Preds ..B1.5
..LN40:
   .loc    1  8  is_stmt 1
        addl      $4, %eax                                      #8.7
..LN41:
   .loc    1  10  is_stmt 1
        vpaddd    %xmm1, %xmm0, %xmm0                           #10.12
..LN42:
   .loc    1  8  is_stmt 1
        cmpl      $10000, %eax                                  #8.7
..LN43:
        jb        ..B1.4        # Prob 66%                      #8.7
..LN44:
                                # LOE rbx r12 r13 r14 r15 eax xmm0 xmm1 ymm2
..B1.7:                         # Preds ..B1.6
..LN45:
   .loc    1  6  is_stmt 1
..LN46:
   .loc    1  15  is_stmt 1
        lea       (%rsp), %rdi                                  #15.7
..LN47:
   .loc    1  6  is_stmt 1
        vextractf128 $1, %ymm2, %xmm0                           #6.7
..LN48:
   .loc    1  15  is_stmt 1
        movl      $-1, %esi                                     #15.7
..LN49:
   .loc    1  6  is_stmt 1
        vaddpd    %xmm0, %xmm2, %xmm1                           #6.7
..LN50:
        vunpckhpd %xmm1, %xmm1, %xmm3                           #6.7
..LN51:
   .loc    1  15  is_stmt 1
        lea       64(%rsp), %r8                                 #15.7
..LN52:
        movq      $0x1208384ff00, %rdx                          #15.7
..LN53:
        movl      $__STRLITPACK_0.0.1, %ecx                     #15.7
..LN54:
        xorl      %eax, %eax                                    #15.7
..LN55:
   .loc    1  6  is_stmt 1
        vaddsd    %xmm3, %xmm1, %xmm4                           #6.7
..LN56:
   .loc    1  15  is_stmt 1
        vmovsd    %xmm4, 64(%rsp)                               #15.7
..LN57:
        movq      $0, (%rsp)                                    #15.7
..LN58:
        vzeroupper                                              #15.7
..LN59:
        call      for_write_seq_lis                             #15.7
..LN60:
                                # LOE rbx r12 r13 r14 r15
..B1.8:                         # Preds ..B1.7
..LN61:
   .loc    1  18  is_stmt 1
        movl      $.2.3_2_kmpc_loc_struct_pack.12, %edi         #18.1
..LN62:
        xorl      %eax, %eax                                    #18.1
..___tag_value_MAIN__.8:                                        #18.1
..LN63:
        call      __kmpc_end                                    #18.1
..___tag_value_MAIN__.9:                                        #
..LN64:
                                # LOE rbx r12 r13 r14 r15
..B1.9:                         # Preds ..B1.8
..LN65:
        movl      $1, %eax                                      #18.1
..LN66:
        movq      %rbp, %rsp                                    #18.1
..LN67:
        popq      %rbp                                          #18.1
..___tag_value_MAIN__.10:                                       #
..LN68:
        ret                                                     #18.1
        .align    16,0x90
..___tag_value_MAIN__.12:                                       #
..LN69:
                                # LOE
..LN70:
# mark_end;
    .type   MAIN__,@function
    .size   MAIN__,.-MAIN__
..LNMAIN__.71:
.LNMAIN__:
    .data
    .align 4
    .align 4
.2.3_2_kmpc_loc_struct_pack.1:
    .long   0
    .long   2
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .quad   .2.3_2__kmpc_loc_pack.0
    .align 4
.2.3_2__kmpc_loc_pack.0:
    .byte   59
    .byte   117
    .byte   110
    .byte   107
    .byte   110
    .byte   111
    .byte   119
    .byte   110
    .byte   59
    .byte   77
    .byte   65
    .byte   73
    .byte   78
    .byte   95
    .byte   95
    .byte   59
    .byte   49
    .byte   59
    .byte   49
    .byte   59
    .byte   59
    .space 3, 0x00  # pad
    .align 4
.2.3_2_kmpc_loc_struct_pack.12:
    .long   0
    .long   2
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .quad   .2.3_2__kmpc_loc_pack.11
    .align 4
.2.3_2__kmpc_loc_pack.11:
    .byte   59
    .byte   117
    .byte   110
    .byte   107
    .byte   110
    .byte   111
    .byte   119
    .byte   110
    .byte   59
    .byte   77
    .byte   65
    .byte   73
    .byte   78
    .byte   95
    .byte   95
    .byte   59
    .byte   49
    .byte   56
    .byte   59
    .byte   49
    .byte   56
    .byte   59
    .byte   59
    .section .rodata, "a"
    .align 16
    .align 8
__NLITPACK_0.0.1:
    .long   0x00000002,0x00000000
    .align 4
__STRLITPACK_0.0.1:
    .byte   48
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
    .data
# -- End  MAIN__
    .section .rodata, "a"
    .space 3, 0x00  # pad
    .align 16
.L_2il0floatpacket.19:
    .long   0x00000001,0x00000002,0x00000003,0x00000004
    .type   .L_2il0floatpacket.19,@object
    .size   .L_2il0floatpacket.19,16
    .align 16
.L_2il0floatpacket.20:
    .long   0x3f800000,0x3f800000,0x3f800000,0x3f800000
    .type   .L_2il0floatpacket.20,@object
    .size   .L_2il0floatpacket.20,16
    .data
    .section .note.GNU-stack, ""
# End
```

ASM output for the non-openmp code

```
    .section .text
.LNDBG_TX:
# mark_description "Intel(R) Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler XE for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 14.0.2.144 Build 2";
# mark_description "0140120";
# mark_description "-O3 -vec-report3 -xhost -S";
    .file "loop_simd.f90"
    .text
..TXTST0:
L__routine_start_MAIN___0:
# -- Begin  MAIN__
# mark_begin;
       .align    16,0x90
    .globl MAIN__
MAIN__:
..B1.1:                         # Preds ..B1.0
..___tag_value_MAIN__.1:                                        #1.9
..LN0:
  .file   1 "loop_simd.f90"
   .loc    1  1  is_stmt 1
        pushq     %rbp                                          #1.9
..___tag_value_MAIN__.3:                                        #
..LN1:
        movq      %rsp, %rbp                                    #1.9
..___tag_value_MAIN__.4:                                        #
..LN2:
        andq      $-128, %rsp                                   #1.9
..LN3:
        subq      $128, %rsp                                    #1.9
..LN4:
        movq      $0x0000117fe, %rsi                            #1.9
..LN5:
        movl      $3, %edi                                      #1.9
..LN6:
        call      __intel_new_feature_proc_init                 #1.9
..LN7:
                                # LOE rbx r12 r13 r14 r15
..B1.10:                        # Preds ..B1.1
..LN8:
        vstmxcsr  (%rsp)                                        #1.9
..LN9:
        movl      $__NLITPACK_0.0.1, %edi                       #1.9
..LN10:
        orl       $32832, (%rsp)                                #1.9
..LN11:
        vldmxcsr  (%rsp)                                        #1.9
..LN12:
        call      for_set_reentrancy                            #1.9
..LN13:
                                # LOE rbx r12 r13 r14 r15
..B1.2:                         # Preds ..B1.10
..LN14:
   .loc    1  6  is_stmt 1
..LN15:
   .loc    1  11  is_stmt 1
        vmovss    .L_2il0floatpacket.0(%rip), %xmm6             #11.28
..LN16:
   .loc    1  9  is_stmt 1
        xorl      %eax, %eax                                    #9.7
..LN17:
   .loc    1  6  is_stmt 1
        vxorpd    %ymm8, %ymm8, %ymm8                           #6.7
..LN18:
        vmovapd   %ymm8, %ymm7                                  #6.7
..LN19:
        vmovapd   %ymm8, %ymm0                                  #6.7
..LN20:
        vmovapd   %ymm8, %ymm1                                  #6.7
..LN21:
        vmovapd   %ymm8, %ymm2                                  #6.7
..LN22:
        vmovapd   %ymm8, %ymm3                                  #6.7
..LN23:
        vmovapd   %ymm8, %ymm4                                  #6.7
..LN24:
        vmovapd   %ymm8, %ymm5                                  #6.7
..LN25:
                                # LOE rbx r12 r13 r14 r15 eax xmm6 ymm0 ymm1 ymm2 ymm3 ymm4 ymm5 ymm7 ymm8
..B1.3:                         # Preds ..B1.5 ..B1.2
..LN26:
        incl      %eax                                          #
..LN27:
   .loc    1  11  is_stmt 1
        vxorps    %xmm9, %xmm9, %xmm9                           #11.28
..LN28:
        vcvtsi2ss %eax, %xmm9, %xmm9                            #11.28
..LN29:
        vdivss    %xmm9, %xmm6, %xmm10                          #11.28
..LN30:
        vcvtss2sd %xmm10, %xmm10, %xmm10                        #11.28
..LN31:
        vmovddup  %xmm10, %xmm11                                #11.28
..LN32:
   .loc    1  10  is_stmt 1
        xorl      %edx, %edx                                    #10.12
..LN33:
   .loc    1  11  is_stmt 1
        vinsertf128 $1, %xmm11, %ymm11, %ymm9                   #11.28
..LN34:
                                # LOE rbx r12 r13 r14 r15 eax edx xmm6 ymm0 ymm1 ymm2 ymm3 ymm4 ymm5 ymm7 ymm8 ymm9
..B1.4:                         # Preds ..B1.4 ..B1.3
..LN35:
   .loc    1  10  is_stmt 1
        addl      $32, %edx                                     #10.12
..LN36:
   .loc    1  11  is_stmt 1
        vaddpd    %ymm9, %ymm8, %ymm8                           #11.17
..LN37:
        vaddpd    %ymm7, %ymm9, %ymm7                           #11.17
..LN38:
        vaddpd    %ymm0, %ymm9, %ymm0                           #11.17
..LN39:
        vaddpd    %ymm1, %ymm9, %ymm1                           #11.17
..LN40:
        vaddpd    %ymm2, %ymm9, %ymm2                           #11.17
..LN41:
        vaddpd    %ymm3, %ymm9, %ymm3                           #11.17
..LN42:
        vaddpd    %ymm4, %ymm9, %ymm4                           #11.17
..LN43:
        vaddpd    %ymm5, %ymm9, %ymm5                           #11.17
..LN44:
   .loc    1  10  is_stmt 1
        cmpl      $10000000, %edx                               #10.12
..LN45:
        jb        ..B1.4        # Prob 99%                      #10.12
..LN46:
                                # LOE rbx r12 r13 r14 r15 eax edx xmm6 ymm0 ymm1 ymm2 ymm3 ymm4 ymm5 ymm7 ymm8 ymm9
..B1.5:                         # Preds ..B1.4
..LN47:
   .loc    1  9  is_stmt 1
        cmpl      $10000, %eax                                  #9.7
..LN48:
        jb        ..B1.3        # Prob 66%                      #9.7
..LN49:
                                # LOE rbx r12 r13 r14 r15 eax xmm6 ymm0 ymm1 ymm2 ymm3 ymm4 ymm5 ymm7 ymm8
..B1.6:                         # Preds ..B1.5
..LN50:
   .loc    1  6  is_stmt 1
        vaddpd    %ymm7, %ymm8, %ymm6                           #6.7
..LN51:
   .loc    1  15  is_stmt 1
        lea       (%rsp), %rdi                                  #15.7
..LN52:
   .loc    1  6  is_stmt 1
        vaddpd    %ymm1, %ymm0, %ymm0                           #6.7
..LN53:
        vaddpd    %ymm3, %ymm2, %ymm1                           #6.7
..LN54:
        vaddpd    %ymm5, %ymm4, %ymm2                           #6.7
..LN55:
        vaddpd    %ymm0, %ymm6, %ymm3                           #6.7
..LN56:
        vaddpd    %ymm2, %ymm1, %ymm4                           #6.7
..LN57:
        vaddpd    %ymm4, %ymm3, %ymm5                           #6.7
..LN58:
   .loc    1  15  is_stmt 1
        movl      $-1, %esi                                     #15.7
..LN59:
        movq      $0x1208384ff00, %rdx                          #15.7
..LN60:
        movl      $__STRLITPACK_0.0.1, %ecx                     #15.7
..LN61:
        xorl      %eax, %eax                                    #15.7
..LN62:
        lea       64(%rsp), %r8                                 #15.7
..LN63:
        movq      $0, (%rsp)                                    #15.7
..LN64:
   .loc    1  6  is_stmt 1
        vextractf128 $1, %ymm5, %xmm7                           #6.7
..LN65:
        vaddpd    %xmm7, %xmm5, %xmm8                           #6.7
..LN66:
        vunpckhpd %xmm8, %xmm8, %xmm9                           #6.7
..LN67:
        vaddsd    %xmm9, %xmm8, %xmm10                          #6.7
..LN68:
   .loc    1  15  is_stmt 1
        vmovsd    %xmm10, 64(%rsp)                              #15.7
..LN69:
        vzeroupper                                              #15.7
..LN70:
        call      for_write_seq_lis                             #15.7
..LN71:
                                # LOE rbx r12 r13 r14 r15
..B1.7:                         # Preds ..B1.6
..LN72:
   .loc    1  18  is_stmt 1
        movl      $1, %eax                                      #18.1
..LN73:
        movq      %rbp, %rsp                                    #18.1
..LN74:
        popq      %rbp                                          #18.1
..___tag_value_MAIN__.6:                                        #
..LN75:
        ret                                                     #18.1
        .align    16,0x90
..___tag_value_MAIN__.8:                                        #
..LN76:
                                # LOE
..LN77:
# mark_end;
    .type   MAIN__,@function
    .size   MAIN__,.-MAIN__
..LNMAIN__.78:
.LNMAIN__:
    .section .rodata, "a"
    .align 8
    .align 8
__NLITPACK_0.0.1:
    .long   0x00000000,0x00000000
    .align 4
__STRLITPACK_0.0.1:
    .byte   48
    .byte   1
    .byte   1
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
    .data
# -- End  MAIN__
    .section .rodata, "a"
    .space 3, 0x00  # pad
    .align 4
.L_2il0floatpacket.0:
    .long   0x3f800000
    .type   .L_2il0floatpacket.0,@object
    .size   .L_2il0floatpacket.0,4
    .data
    .section .note.GNU-stack, ""
# End
```

Comment: What asm do you get?  (Most compilers accept a `-S` option to produce asm output).  A test-case where all the inputs are compile-time constants is probably doing to distort things.  Also, what hardware?  Intel Haswell?  AMD Bulldozer?  (A CPU model number is fine).

Comment: Also the compiler version may be important.

Comment: I added the ouput of -S flag. On the first lines is the Intel compiler version. Details of the processors: Intel Xeon E5-2660 "Sandy Bridge" processors at 2.2GHz

Comment: Without omp simd directives, the compiler may take more liberties to shortcut redundant loops.  Anyway, there is little point in comparing incorrect simd code. As with omp parallel, including a reduction without the  corresponding reduction clause may produce wrong results.

Comment: I also tried "!$omp simd collapse(2) reduction(+:x)" and the time was similar than without the reduction clause.

Answer (score 5):

**With OpenMP**, Ifort is using SIMD to vectorize the outer loop (over `i`), so essentially all the time is spent doing

```
## set up ymm3 with 4 copies of 1.0/(1.0*i),
# and j = %edx = 0
..B1.5:                              do {
    incl      %edx                   #   j++
    vaddpd    %ymm3, %ymm2, %ymm2    # ymm3 + ymm2  =>  ymm2
    cmpl      $10000000, %edx        } while(j<10000000);
    jb        ..B1.5        # Prob 99%
```

10M iterations of `vaddpd` will completely dominate the cost of everything outside the loop, so all that matters is that this inner-loop is executed 10k / 4 times.  (note the `add  $4, %eax` / `cmp   $10000, %eax` / `jb`, with a branch target back to before the inner loop.)

Since it's only using a single accumulator, throughput is limited by the loop-carried dependency (3 cycles).

---

### Without OpenMP:

It's still doing the full amount of work, not optimizing away any of the loops.

It auto-vectorizes like with `#pragma openmp`, but using multiple accumulators for increased parallelism.  Multiple add instructions can be in-flight at once, instead of having each one depend on the previous.

The setup for the inner loop is very similar, and then the inner loop is:

```
## set up ymm3 with 4 copies of 1.0/(1.0*i),
..B1.4:
    addl      $32, %edx                                     #10.12
    vaddpd    %ymm9, %ymm8, %ymm8       # ymm8 + ymm9  =>  ymm8
    vaddpd    %ymm7, %ymm9, %ymm7       # ymm7 + ymm9  =>  ymm7
    vaddpd    %ymm0, %ymm9, %ymm0       # ymm0 + ymm9  =>  ymm0
    vaddpd    %ymm1, %ymm9, %ymm1       # ...
    vaddpd    %ymm2, %ymm9, %ymm2
    vaddpd    %ymm3, %ymm9, %ymm3
    vaddpd    %ymm4, %ymm9, %ymm4
    vaddpd    %ymm5, %ymm9, %ymm5
    cmpl      $10000000, %edx
    jb        ..B1.4        # Prob 99%

    # then combine the 8 vector accumulators down to one, and horizontal sum that.
```

8 accumulators could keep 8 `vaddpd`s in flight at once, but the latency is only 3 cycles on Intel SnB/IvB (See [Agner Fog's insn tables](http://agner.org/optimize/)).  You didn't say what microarchitecture you're using, but I could infer Sandybridge/Ivybridge from the fact that `-xhost` uses AVX1 but not AVX2.  (broadcast with `vmovddup` / `vinsertf128`, rather than AVX2 `vbroadcastsd %xmm9, %ymm9`)

**This perfectly explains the 3x speed ratio:  26.535 / 8.940 = 2.97 ~= 3**.  (`vaddpd` has a throughput of one per clock on pre-Skylake Intel CPUs, latency=3.  This version is limited by throughput rather than latency, because of the increased instruction-level parallelism).

Unrolling with this many accumulators will help for Skylake, where FP add has 4 cycle latency and two per cycle throughput.  (SKL dropped the lower-latency dedicated vector FP add unit from port 1, and runs it in the improved 4c-latency FMA units on ports 0 and 1.)

Comment: sorry, I attached that already. Thanks for your useful comments.

Comment: @armando: updated.  Turns out that without the OpenMP pragma, ifort auto-vectorizes with more instruction-level parallelism.

Comment: lacking of experience with SIMD instructions, every example I try with SIMD cannot beat the performance of the same code without SIMD. Do you have a fortran example where SIMD instructions display a better performance than standard code? Thanks.

Comment: @armando: You mean with `!$omp simd`?  Don't call that an "instruction", because "SIMD instruction" already has a specific technical meaning: an assembly instruction that operates on a SIMD vector register.  e.g. [`shufps` is a SIMD instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SHUFPS.html).  You're getting a 4x speedup from SIMD in this example, since `vaddpd ymm` is doing 4 elements in parallel.

Comment: @armando: An OpenMP directive is only going to help in cases where the compiler doesn't already auto-vectorize.  I've seen cases like that for C with gcc/clang, esp. without `-ffast-math`.  OpenMP allows the compiler to reorder FP operations, even though FP math is not strictly associative.  Without `-ffast-math`, many optimizations aren't allowed because they'd round differently, or produce different intermediate results (which might overflow).  I don't have any ifort examples because 1. I don't know Fortran, and 2. I don't use Intel's compilers.

Comment: @armando, I don't really get the point of `omp simd`. It only really makes sense if a compiler does not auto-vectorize but I think it takes a lot of effort to do good auto-vectorization so I doubt that the OpenMP group can compete with the auto-vectorization group of a compiler.  There are a few small things `omp simd` can do though which I'll explain in the next comment.

Comment: @armando, my comments are for C/C++.  `omp simd` only needs `-O2` to vectorize whereas auto-vectorization needs `-O3` (or another option with `-O2`).  Additionally, `omp simd` will vectorize depenency chains with `-O2` whereas auto-vectorization needs `-Ofast`.  Another feature is that `omp simd align` can be used to inform the compiler that a pointer is alligned.  Other compilers have builtins to do this, GCC and Clang can use the same builtin, ICC uses a different one. Using `omp simd align` it works for ICC and GCC. I don't know if Clang uses `omp simd` yet, MSVC does not (and no builtin).

Comment: @Zboson: *I doubt that the OpenMP group can compete with the auto-vectorization group of a compiler*: `omp simd` was only ever supposed to be a way to trigger the compiler's existing ability to auto-vectorize.  It's great if you have some loops that the compiler would auto-vectorize badly.  Also, the `-ffast-math` (or whichever specific sub-options `omp simd` triggers) for specific loops only is a big deal.  Depending on the code, you might well not be comfortable compiling the whole thing with `-ffast-math`, and not confident that testing would catch any problems it caused.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes, that's another potentially useful feature of `omp simd`. It allows you do use `-ffast-math` in some sense (at least for associative math) for only a region of a file instead of for the whole translation unit.  It has several potentially useful features but nothing ground breaking like it has with threading. I'm not aware of any alternative for threading which is convenient as OpenMP especially with thread pools.

Comment: I have since learned that `omp simd` with ICC is useful. I still don't see the point with GCC.  I mean with `-Ofast` with ICC does not optimize as much as `omp simd` but with GCC I think `-Ofast` is as good as `omp simd`.

Answer (score 3):

You may be better off using SIMD for the inner loop only. Then You can use !$OMP parallel on the outer loop.
As the I is related to the outer loop, you could/should probably also reverse the outer and inner loops.
If you allocated another variable for the 1.0/(1.0*i) , then perhaps that could be vectorised. Then the reduction assumes that the new variable is a vector that is in the heap, and not a value that is private in OMP.

These things usually take a bit to work out...

Answer (score -1):

SIMD instructions are intended to improve the performance of code that operates on vectors or arrays. Your sample code only operates on a scalar variable, it is therefore unsurprising that forcing vectorization does not improve performance!

Comment: There is parallelism here, from doing 2 or 4 `i` values in parallel in different elements of a single vector.  I assume it's slower because it defeats some kind of loop transformation that optimizes away part of the work of the repeat-loop.