# Fortran calling C: How do I get an efficient vectorised function

Tags: c, fortran, vectorization, simd, intel-fortran

I have to call a C function from Fortran, but I want to do this in a vectorised loop. I am working with Intel 16.0.3 compilers on Linux.

So the options are: I can try and get the function to inline or I can use a SIMD function (I want to use OpenMP SIMD for this, I want it to be portable and I already use OpenMP).

If I call Fortran from Fortran it works both ways. For passing arguments I use the linear/ref clause to pass a reference to a vector of values rather than a vector of references and this seems to work efficiently. But in C the linear/ref clause is not recognised.

I can get the function to nominally vectorise but it is inserting gathers and scatters and performance is no better than scalar (at least for my small test function).

If I put `linear(ref(r,s))` in the Fortran interface block I get the message

> The UVAL or REF modifiers must not be used on a dummy argument with
>   the VALUE attribute.

I can get the performance using the trick of passing by value from Fortran and returning a value as the function return. This produces a vectorised function, and performance is good, but unfortunately my real function needs to return more than one value.

If I try to inline the C function, it just won't work. The opt-report just tells me the callsite cannot be inlined. This is true even with a scalar function. I cannot get C functions to inline into Fortran at all. I am using ipo to try and do this. I have wondered if the inlining problem could be Fortran passing a pointer to a pointer? But then as the code gives the right answers it seems that it somehow acceptable.

The test code (passing pointers) is essentially...

Fortran caller

```
Use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING
….
real*8, allocatable :: r(:),s(:)  .
….

interface
 integer simd_c_func(r,s) bind(c, name="simd_c_func")
 !$OMP DECLARE SIMD(simd_c_func)
 import :: C_DOUBLE
 real(kind=C_DOUBLE), intent(inout):: r,s
end interface

allocate.... 

!$OMP SIMD

do i=1,N
  ierror=simd_c_func(r(i),s(i))
enddo
```

C callee

```
#pragma omp declare simd
int simd_c_func(double *r, double *s) {
 (*r)+=(*s);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a test program that compiles?

Comment: These things are very new, the support is patchy and it varies from compiler version to version. Include the actual compiler output and try to make a MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: OK, I will paste a working example as soon as possible. I have the code on a standalone machine with the relevant compiler package. Waiting for a transfer.

Answer (score 2):

The `LINEAR(REF())` is pretty new, so one can only hope that some LINEAR using OMP and CONTIGUOUS can get you joy.

The message:

> The UVAL or REF modifiers must not be used on a dummy argument with the VALUE attribute."

indicates that it is doing value and on the stack. I thought C arrays were in `heap`? but maybe you need a `-heap` switch?

**C-side:**

I would suggest you add `linear` to you `#pragma`

```
#pragma omp declare simd linear(r,s)
```

Have you looked at using `#pragma vector aligned`? and also `#pragma ivdep`?
I am assuming that (*r) is a reference (in heap)

**F90-Side**

I would suggest you replace:

```
real(8), allocatable :: r(:), s(:)
```

with

```
!$DIR ATTRIBUTES ALIGN:64                           :: R, S
REAL(KIND=8), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE, CONTIGUOUS :: R, S
```

The only real change here is the 64bit alignment and the contiguous.
One can also use a switch -align array64byte

If `ierror` is not an array then do you want one? or do you perhaps need to use a first/last private or a reduction clause on `ierror`? I would probably use reduction.

`!$OMP SIMD` then goes to:

```
!$OMP DO SIMD REDUCTION(ierror)
```

But as you mention that you need more than one value then maybe you need to allocate `ierror`?

And I am interested in how the interface knows that it gets a return value of zero. Seem like you have to have INTEGER FUNCTION somewhere in the interface.

**Linking-Compiling side:**

If C produced an `F90-` MODULE then the USE  would allow it to see deep enough into the C code to inline or otherwise help. So you may need the `-IPO` on the compiler/link to allow the F90 to understand what it can do with the C callee.

Answer (score 0):

After a sleep, I am wondering if you should just have a void, and use subroutine on your interface specification?

The other option seems like it would be:
INTEGER FUNCTION simd_c_func and then use a REDUCTION in the SIMD on the FORTRAN Side.

But neither of those address the actual compiler message you got.
And I see you already used -IPO.

You may try replacing:
LINEAR(REF(R,S))
with
LINEAR(REF(R), REF(S))

Comment: This should probably be an edit to your previous answer.  A horizontal ruler (`---`) is nice for separating sections, and maybe use a header in a big font.  So I'd suggest making an edit and then deleting this 2nd answer.  Welcome to Stackoverflow, BTW.  I didn't know compilers could do link-time-optimization between languages; that's cool.  (I don't know fortran though; I'm seeing this question because of the SIMD tag, so I can't add anything much to this question myself.).

Comment: Also, you should merge your accounts into one, if [this is you as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38436532/224132)

Comment: Peter how do I merge them? I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: IDK, I never created a 2nd account in the first place.  I think it's supposed to be possible; try searching on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ or http://meta.stackexchange.com/